# display an overlay div when user wait for load new page

Tags: php, css, wordpress, function, overlay

I use WordPress and in my pages, there is bellow div that shows a loading spinner at registration form submit and that works fine. but as default it has display:none and I want to use this when the user waiting to load a new page (when the user clicks on the button or on a link before the page reload, not at first waiting page), is there any idea?

```
<div class="dig_load_overlay">
    <div class="dig_load_content">
        <div class="dig_spinner">
            <div class="dig_double-bounce1"></div>
            <div class="dig_double-bounce2"></div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: you can use the jquery onclick event for showing this loader and you have to hide it again when your action is complete

Comment: It'll be easier to help you if you share your CSS.

Answer (score 1):

Using Jquery:

```
$(window).unload(function () {
    $('.dig_load_overlay').show();
});
```

Javascript only:

```
window.addEventListener('beforeunload', function() {
    document.getElementById('dig_load_overlay').style.display = 'block';
});
```

Comment: thankyou. but I do not know any thing about java. I try to add this script to the head and body wirh function.php but its not work. is it possible to help me to use this?

Comment: Try to put it inside a <script> tag before closing <body> tag, just like this:  <Script>...</script></body>